# Using the generic type 'PagedList.StaticPagedList<T>' requires 1 type arguments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am working on user roles using Asp.net MVC. I am stuck while working on Admin section. I have mentioned one question above and the second question is similar which is **Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' requires 1 type arguments**

Here is my code.

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchStringUserNameOrEmail, string currentFilter, int? page)
        {
            try
            {
                int intPage = 1;
                int intPageSize = 5;
                int intTotalPageCount = 0;
                if (searchStringUserNameOrEmail != null)
                {
                    intPage = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (currentFilter != null)
                    {
                        searchStringUserNameOrEmail = currentFilter;
                        intPage = page ?? 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        searchStringUserNameOrEmail = "";
                        intPage = page ?? 1;
                    }
                }
                ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchStringUserNameOrEmail;
                List col_UserDTO = new List();
                int intSkip = (intPage - 1) * intPageSize;
                intTotalPageCount = UserManager.Users
                    .Where(x => x.UserName.Contains(searchStringUserNameOrEmail))
                    .Count();
                var result = UserManager.Users
                    .Where(x => x.UserName.Contains(searchStringUserNameOrEmail))
                    .OrderBy(x => x.UserName)
                    .Skip(intSkip)
                    .Take(intPageSize)
                    .ToList();
                foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    ExpandedUserDTO objUserDTO = new ExpandedUserDTO();
                    objUserDTO.UserName = item.UserName;
                    objUserDTO.Email = item.Email;
                    objUserDTO.LockoutEndDateUtc = item.LockoutEndDateUtc;
                    col_UserDTO.Add(objUserDTO);
                }
                // Set the number of pages
// Error appears here
                var _UserDTOAsIPagedList =
                    new StaticPagedList
                    (
                        col_UserDTO, intPage, intPageSize, intTotalPageCount
                        );
                return View(_UserDTOAsIPagedList);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error: " + ex);
                List col_UserDTO = new List(); // Error appears here
                return View(col_UserDTO.ToPagedList(1, 25));
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StaticPagedList` is generic. You need to supply the type of collection(for col_UserDTO), in your case `List`:

```
var _UserDTOAsIPagedList =
   new StaticPagedList<List<ExpandedUserDTO>>
      (
         col_UserDTO, intPage, intPageSize, intTotalPageCount
      );
```

See http://www.programering.com/a/MTN2gDNwATM.html

You may need to change `List col_UserDTO` references to `List<ExpandedUserDTO> col_UserDTO`

Comment: Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' requires 1 type arguments. Getting this error now.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
var _UserDTOAsIPagedList =
   new StaticPagedList<ExpandedUserDTO>
      (
        col_UserDTO, intPage, intPageSize, intTotalPageCount
      );
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.